# How to use morea theorem to prove $\mathcal{D}$ where $D=\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$ is a closed banach subalgebra?

Tags: functional-analysis

Where C(D) consists all analytic functions interior of D. I can show it is normed linear space. Is it complete with respect to $||f||=\int_D|f(\zeta)|d\zeta$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please share your own progress on the problem and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Your suggestion is useful. Apply the Morera theorem which shows holomorphy of the function through the integral formulas.

Comment: i am having problem in proving C(D) is a banach algebra